# Is it more secure to just use single sign on options for my website?

Tags: security, single-sign-on

I just went to a workshop on web security, and it was kinda depressing and terrifying. We spoke about how hackable so many different aspects of web security are. Weak passwords, email reset links as a hacker's work around, and never mind distributed login attempts.

So, I was thinking what if I only use single sign on. Google, Facebook, Github etc...

Would I successfully be shifting the security burden onto these entities? Or are their still aspects of authentication I'm responsible for? I suppose SSL is one. Are there any others?

Comment: imo, Don't get depressed. The real point to take away is that the more 'layers' of 'security' that you have then the more difficult it is for 'casual attackers'. The first thing to do is to look at: [OWASP Top Ten Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) and make sure your site avoids these issues. At least it will ensure the 'naughty people' move on to easier targets? Think of houses with obvious security systems being broken into? Most people will try and find an easier target?

Comment: @RyanVincent That's really helpful. Thanks! : )

Comment: There are also services, that are not expensive, that will scan your website and report any 'weakness' such as software versions, common exploits that allow them  read things that should be hidden etc. Again, these can be scary at first but can provide useful information so you can remove the obvious weaknesses. Just being aware of them is a major part of the issue. Again, just examine the reports. It may not be worthwhile doing anything other than upgrading to the latest versions of your software.